# How to speed up blob pixel list searching with floodfill?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to remove connected pixels that are smaller than 100 pixels from an gray black&white image to get a better result in ocr. To get the connected pixels, I used floodfill method and it returns the blob which is the list of pixels. Then add the blobs into the list of blobs if the blob size is bigger than 100 pixels. After that, clear the whole thing and redraw pixels using the list of blobs.

The process works as intended but it takes 4 minutes to process a small image. I hope there is better way or ways to make it faster.

I tried to use Aforge's BlobCounter bc = new BlobCounter();. It only find the whole image as one single blob and it didn't work.

```
private List<Blob1> getbloblist(Bitmap Bmp1, int thold)//thold=100
        {
            List<Blob1> bloblist = new List<Blob1>();
            List<System.Drawing.Point> allplist = new List<System.Drawing.Point>();

            for (int x1 = 0; x1 < Bmp1.Width; x1++)
            {
                for (int y1 = 0; y1 < Bmp1.Height; y1++)
                {
                    FF3result ff3result1 = new FF3result();                    
                    System.Drawing.Point cpoint1 = new System.Drawing.Point(x1, y1);

                    if(allplist.Contains(cpoint1))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    Color chk1 = getcolorfast(cpoint1, Bmp1);//used lockbits
                    ff3result1 = FloodFillR(Bmp1, cpoint1, chk1, Color.Red, 100, allplist);
                    allplist = ff3result1.allplist;

                    if (ff3result1.Blob1.Size > thold)
                    {
                        bloblist.Add(ff3result1.Blob1);
                    }
                }
            }
            return bloblist;
        }

private FF3result FloodFillR(Bitmap bmp, System.Drawing.Point pt, Color targetColor, Color replacementColor, int sens, List<System.Drawing.Point> allplist)
        {
            FF3result ff3result1 = new FF3result();

            LockBitmap lockBitmap = new LockBitmap(bmp);
            lockBitmap.LockBits();

            Stack<System.Drawing.Point> pixels = new Stack<System.Drawing.Point>();

            pixels.Push(pt);

            while (pixels.Count > 0)
            {
                System.Drawing.Point a = pixels.Pop();
                if (a.X < lockBitmap.Width && a.X > 0 &&
                        a.Y < lockBitmap.Height && a.Y > 0)//make sure we stay within bounds
                {
                    pixel1 pixel1 = new pixel1();
                    pixel1.color1 = targetColor;
                    pixel1.x1 = a.X;
                    pixel1.y1 = a.Y;
                    System.Drawing.Point pt2 = new System.Drawing.Point(a.X, a.Y);
                    if (!allplist.Contains(pt2))
                    {
                        allplist.Add(pt2);
                        if (!ff3result1.Blob1.Blob.Contains(pixel1))
                        {                            
                            if (mypic.ColorMatch(sens, lockBitmap.GetPixel(a.X, a.Y), targetColor))//colormatch sense
                            {
                                //lockBitmap.SetPixel(a.X, a.Y, replacementColor);
                                ff3result1.Blob1.Blob.Add(pixel1);
                                ff3result1.Blob1.Size++;

                                pixels.Push(new System.Drawing.Point(a.X - 1, a.Y));
                                pixels.Push(new System.Drawing.Point(a.X + 1, a.Y));
                                pixels.Push(new System.Drawing.Point(a.X, a.Y - 1));
                                pixels.Push(new System.Drawing.Point(a.X, a.Y + 1));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            lockBitmap.UnlockBits();
            ff3result1.allplist = allplist;

            return ff3result1;
        }
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Maybe make `allplist` a `HashSet` so that `Contains()` is O(1) instead of O(n)? That's just off the top of my head...

Comment: Maybe what I'm trying to do is 'connected component labeling'. I'm looking at "https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/336915/Connected-Component-Labeling-Algorithm". This method use dictionary and its completely different from mine. I'm not sure if it is faster.

Comment: OMG. Thank you very much. I changed allplist to HashSet as you said. Before change: 456.3341008 seconds, After change: 35.2850182 seconds. 1300% improvement!